# Replace everything except text between specific delimiters with whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, text-processing

I have following text file (file may contain up to few hundred lines):

```
<% some important text %> something <% important stuff %>
not important stuff <not important stuff>
<% some
       important text
%>
```

Basiclly I need to replace anything that is not between "<% %>" delimiters with whitespaces. There may be multiple occurences of <% text %> in one line. Also, <% %> block may be spread over multiple lines, as in above example.
Result should look like this:

```
<% some important text %>           <% important stuff %>

<% some
       important text
%>
```

Any advice how to handle it? Tried regular expressions, it is easy to get <% text %> but that's not enough, I need to put whitespaces everywhere the pattern is not matched.
Will appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Can the tags be nested? Is it possible to escape an opening or closing token? As in, can the `some important text` contain the string: `"%>"` or `\\%>` or something like that?

Comment: Tags cannot be nested, text between tags cannot have "<% %>" in any form (text outside tags as well)

Comment: Are you trying to replace each one of out-of-block characters with a space or all of them with one space?

Comment: I need to replace each out of block character with space, i.e. "something" must be replaced with 9 spaces.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be working with `\G` metacharacter:

```
(%>\R*|\G\R*(?!<%)).
```

and replace with `$1`  (mind the trailing space)

See regex [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/foE60w/1)

Regex breakdown:

- `(` Start of capturing group #1

  - `%>\R*` Match `%>` and any optional trailing newline characters
  - `|` Or
  - `\G\R*(?!<%)` Match start of subject string or where previous match ends then any optional trailing newline characters that are not preceded by `<%`
- `)` End of capturing group #1
- `.` Match a single character (except a newline)

Java code:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(%>\\R*|\\G\\R*(?!<%)).", "$1 ");
```

See [live demo here](https://ideone.com/dl9kj9)

**Disclaimer**

This assumes that,

1. You do not have nested blocks
2. `<%` and `%>` delimiters are correctly paired
3. `<%` and `%>` never happens outside of blocks

Comment: Doesn't work with unimportant (multi-line) text before first important block.

Comment: What block do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to `<% xxx %>` as a block of important text.

Comment: Did you see the live demo?

Comment: The demo doesn't have unimportant text before first block of important text, and the unimportant text doesn't get blanked out if it does. `"a<%b%>c<%d%>e"` becomes `"a<%b%> <%d%> "`, and `a` should have been replaced by space too.

Comment: Why those newline \R matches? Can you not use DOTALL (?s) mode?

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel I'm retaining newline characters which means I have to capture them separately. The reason for having `$1` in replacement string.

Comment: @revo Oh, so unimportant newlines are in fact important! Missed that. It doesn't say in the question but the example shows so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?s)(?<=%>).*?(?=<%)
```

It has positive look-behind(-ahead), `(?s)` turns on single-line option (can be different in your regex engine).

Comment: Then do what with that regex?

Comment: @Andreas, obviously replace all the matches of this regex with empty string :D

Comment: But OP doesn't want to replace text with spaces, not empty string. That is a big part of the difficulty of the question, that this answer is not covering.

Answer (score 0):

Split the whole text with the "<%" token.

Search each of the substrings for the "%>" literal.

Replace everything after that position with spaces.

Rejoin all substrings.

Comment: thats way longer he's looking for a regex solution

Comment: @faris - The OP doesn't stipulate that a regex is desired, just that it was tried without success. This is indeed one viable way to acquire a solution that will undoubtedly work if done properly.